# PHP Associative Array to JSON

Tags: php, laravel

I need to have data output in a very specific format to be used with something.

```
$product = Product::with('product_attribute_values', 'product_attribute_values.product_attribute_key')->find(2);

$product_decoded = json_decode($product, true);
```

I need to extract product attribute values into a specific format and it currently looks like:

[image]

I wish for it be like:

```
{
    "Material":"Plastic", 
    "Printing Method":"Pad", 
    "Ink Colour":"Black", 
    "Barrel Colour":"Silver", 
    "Grip Colour":"Black"
}
```

I have attempted this:

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($product_decoded['product_attribute_values'] as $pav) {
     $array = [
          $pav['product_attribute_key']['name'] => $pav['name']
     ];

     array_push($final_array, $array);
}

return json_encode($final_array);
```

This results in data looking like:

```
[
    {"Material":"Plastic"},
    {"Printing Method":"Pad"},
    {"Ink Colour":"Black"},
    {"Barrel Colour":"Silver"},
    {"Grip Colour":"Black"}
]
```

How would this be achieved?

Comment: do not use `array_push`, use directly as `$final_array[$pav['product_attribute_key']['name']] => $pav['name']`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd - Laravel v5.8

Comment: May be - `->plick('product_attribute_values.name', 'product_attribute_key.name')->all()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach($product_decoded['product_attribute_values'] as $pav) {
     $array[$pav['product_attribute_key']['name']] = $pav['name'];
}

return json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

For something like this you could use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections):

```
return collect($product_decoded['product_attribute_values'])
    ->pluck('name', 'product_attribute_key.name')
    ->toJson();
```

Alternatively, you could use the [array helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-array-pluck):

```
$finalArray = Arr::pluck($product_decoded['product_attribute_values'],'name', 'product_attribute_key.name' );

return json_encode($finalArray);
```

Comment: @SougataBose I'm not sure it can be as it would trying to access the relationship as a column on the initial table (if I'm not mistaken). The QueryBuilder should ultimately return a collection so it will be possible from that.

Comment: I meant to ask this. :) . I am not sure too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have it in an object instead of an array.

```
$item = array("Material"=>"Plastic", "Printing Method"=>"Pad", "Ink Colour"=>"Black", "Barrel Colour"=>"Silver", "Grip Colour"=>"Black");

echo json_encode($item);
```

will result in this JSON:

```
[
    {"Material":"Plastic"},
    {"Printing Method":"Pad"},
    {"Ink Colour":"Black"},
    {"Barrel Colour":"Silver"},
    {"Grip Colour":"Black"}
]
```

Which is correct JSON array syntax.

In order to get

```
{
    "Material":"Plastic", 
    "Printing Method":"Pad", 
    "Ink Colour":"Black", 
    "Barrel Colour":"Silver", 
    "Grip Colour":"Black"
}
```

You would need soemthing like

```
$item->Material = "Plastic";
$item->PrintingMethod = "Pad";
$item->InkColour = "Black";
$item->Barrel Colour = "Silver";
$item->GripColour = "Black;

json_encode($item);
```